# Promble with showing the arm on rviz using ros industrial package?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi~

on [ros_org_video_rc1](http://code.google.com/p/swri-ros-pkg/) package

When I run

```
  roslaunch sia10d_mesh_arm_navigation planning_scene_warehouse_viewer_sia10d_mesh.launch
```

But there is no arm model on rviz.

[http://imgur.com/0UK3C](https://imgur.com/0UK3C)

And I also found some error messages :

```
  ../../intel/intel_bufmgr_gem.c:1158: Error writing data to buffer 31: (0 36672) Bad address .
  ../../intel/intel_bufmgr_gem.c:1158: Error writing data to buffer 33: (0 36672) Bad address .
  ../../intel/intel_bufmgr_gem.c:1158: Error writing data to buffer 37: (0 166656) Bad address .
  ../../intel/intel_bufmgr_gem.c:1158: Error writing data to buffer 39: (0 166656) Bad address .
  ../../intel/intel_bufmgr_gem.c:1158: Error writing data to buffer 44: (0 116160) Bad address .
  ../../intel/intel_bufmgr_gem.c:1158: Error writing data to buffer 46: (0 116160) Bad address .
  ../../intel/intel_bufmgr_gem.c:1158: Error writing data to buffer 49: (0 181824) Bad address .
  ../../intel/intel_bufmgr_gem.c:1158: Error writing data to buffer 51: (0 181824) Bad address .
  ../../intel/intel_bufmgr_gem.c:1158: Error writing data to buffer 54: (0 127296) Bad address .
  ../../intel/intel_bufmgr_gem.c:1158: Error writing data to buffer 56: (0 127296) Bad address .
  ../../intel/intel_bufmgr_gem.c:1158: Error writing data to buffer 60: (0 146880) Bad address .
  ../../intel/intel_bufmgr_gem.c:1158: Error writing data to buffer 62: (0 146880) Bad address .
  ../../intel/intel_bufmgr_gem.c:1158: Error writing data to buffer 67: (0 24768) Bad address .
  ../../intel/intel_bufmgr_gem.c:1158: Error writing data to buffer 69: (0 24768) Bad address .
  ../../intel/intel_bufmgr_gem.c:1158: Error writing data to buffer 71: (0 150528) Bad address .
  ../../intel/intel_bufmgr_gem.c:1158: Error writing data to buffer 73: (0 150528) Bad address .
```

How to solve it?
thank you

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/30020/promble-with-showing-the-arm-on-rviz-using-ros-industrial-package?/) by [Eric](https://answers.ros.org/users/2016/eric/) on ROS Answers with karma: 23 on 2012-03-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Looks like it might be a driver issue.  Check out the answer to this question: http://answers.ros.org/question/10982/error-writing-data-to-buffer-urdf-model-in-rviz

---

Originally posted by [sedwards](https://answers.ros.org/users/78/sedwards/) with karma: 1601 on 2012-03-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2